# PHP file to load on startup

Tags: php

Is there any way in php to load a file name other than  file with name index?

Comment: It depends what php framework you're using. Of course every framework can be configured. Give us more info what you're using.

Comment: You can change the index file name at the webserver configuration level, depending on which one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is limited but based on my understanding you can edit the .htaccess file to change the index file from loading first as default. I suggest you Click [here](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/htaccess-change-index-page)!